# Size calculation of XML row wise in oracle database

Tags: sql, xml, plsql, oracle11g, clob

Can anyone please guide me how can i calculate the size of XMl file row wise stored in my oracle database. There is a column of CLOB type which is storing complete XML.

I also searched on Google, but it's navigating me on dbms_lob.getlength(REQUEST_DATA) which I believe is returning me length (number of characters) of the XML and not size of it.

Comment: What is the difference to you between the length and the size?  Are you just looking for the size in bytes rather than the size in characters (knowing that the size in bytes will vary based on the character set)?

Comment: I understand, size in bytes and size in characters are two different parameters and size is directly proportional to the number of characters in  the file. So I want to deduce the size in bytes that a xml is consuming in memory.....Also, it would be pretty interesting to know how oracle store that xml with all metadata of it so it definetly increase the actual size of xml while storing it in database......I hope this make sense....

Answer (score 0):

Is this sufficient for you:

```
 select dbms_lob.getlength(YOUR_COLUMN)/1000000 MegaByte from YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: Tomas, thanks for your suggestion, but its returning 4000 Bytes for all the records....

Comment: @Tomas: If the content has more then 4000 bytes then it will consider only first 4000 bytes. Hence it will provide result for the partial data only.